# System.out.println("") changes the behavior of the program

Tags: java, while-loop

I have the following code :

```java
        boolean running = true;
        while (running) {
            MathStackJPanel focused = Main.frame.mainPanel.focused;
            //System.out.print("");
            if (focused != null) {
                Point p = focused.getMousePosition();
                ExpressionComponent ep = focused.getUnderPoint(p);
            }
        }
```

`focused.getUnderPoint(p)` is supposed to print something (for debugging) but does not. As soon as I uncomment `System.out.print("")`, the code works as intended and I see things printed in the console (from `focused.getUnderPoint(p)`). Why does that simple line that is supposed to literally do nothing totally modify the behavior of my code ? Also, I can tell that the code inside the while loop is not being run AT ALL because when I uncomment `System.out.print("")` an exception is thrown (as expected), in a certain scenario.

Does java optimize away my while loop even though it shouldn't ?

Someone asked for a better example :

```java
    public static Object b = null;

    public static void a() {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            b = 4;
        });

        thread.start();

        while (true) {
            //System.out.print("");
            if (b != null) {
                a();
            }
        }
    }
```

Uncomment the line to make it work (prints ok)

Comment: Please show a complete example we can run which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Likely there is some other factor in play here. Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: If a `System.out.println()` changes something that's one of two likely reasons: 1. it doesn't actually change anything, but recompiling actually made the code run that you thought was running before or 2. the synchronization involved in that statement changes the timing of your code slightly and works around a race condition in your code.

Comment: See edit, should be a bit more clear as to what happens

Comment: Ah yes: `b` is not volatile, so reading it in an endless loop is allowed to never see a new value. The `System.out.println()` *incidentally* creates a read barrier which means `b` will be re-read and the cached value isn't re-used. Make `b` volatile to fix it without the `System.out.println`.